# Activate SVN Server sor ssh+svn:// connections on Mac OS X 10.6 Server

Tags: macos, svn, svn-server

I have Mac OS X 10.6.8 Server. It has svn 1.6.17 installed. So I installed the latest version (1.7.8) using macports: sudo port install subversion.

Now, if I type svnserve --version in my terminal window I get the new version: 1.7.8. However, if I remotely check that the new svnserver is active with:

ssh username@host svnserve --version

I get the old version 1.6.17. Also, it seems that I have to manually add the new version to each user's path.

How can I activate it SVN Server globally on this machine?

Thanks,

Nick,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

macports only updates the .profile PATH. You need to add the same PATH string to the local or global .bashrc file.